# Export to CAD in ModelBuilder - Boolean stops model

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, cad, error-000229

I have a model that runs within ArcMap where it takes the selected features from several feature classes in an ArcMap session and converts them to a dwg using the export to CAD tool. The main model consists of a nested model called VCSetup as shown in the screenshot.  VCSetup takes the selected features, uses "Get Count" to get the number of features and then "Calculate Value" is used as a boolean where if the number of selected features is greater than 0 and less than 10000, it is true and else, it is false.  Calculate Value is set as a precondition to the next step, "Copy Features". These features are then set as parameters to feed the export to CAD tool.  The issue is, if the "Calculate Value" is false (no features from a feature class are selected), the "Copy Features" does not run and therefore, the Export to CAD tool fails as it says "Error 000229: Cannot open in_memory\Water_Pipes".  The model includes every feature class in the mxd, however, there will be feature classes that have no selected records when exporting to CAD. How do we get around this where even though there are no features selected in some feature classes, the tool proceeds to export features that ARE selected?[image: Main/Parent Model]

[image: VCSetup sub/nested model]